# In Windows 7, is it possible to grab the title of the main window of a GUI application without a user being logged in? I know, immediate answer is no

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

edit: edited for what I hope is clarity

There's a GUI application that has a single main window. That main window has text in it's title bar; I was tasked to retrieve the text in the main window title bar.

Normally, if an user is logged in, the application starts just fine and I can grab the title of main window using a PowerShell, by invoking System.Diagnostic.Process.MainWindowTitle, no problem.

However, I need to grab this same information when no user is logged in. I intended to write a script or a small console application that would be launched by the task scheduler to do so. It's strange, I know: I need to start this application when no user is logged on the system, and retrieve the text in the title bar of its sole main window.

I know that when no user is logged in, the task scheduler will obviously still dutifully try to run scripts or executables. However, because no user is logged, these scheduled executables or scripts will not have access to the Windows *GUI subsystem*. Therefore, if a scheduled task tries to start an application requiring a window to be drawn, well, that window won't be drawn.

This means I can't simply schedule a script that will launch this GUI application, get the text in the tile bar and then kill the application (I can't do this because the application will never have it's main window drawn).

I have some ideas and I was hoping for input on them (or even another alternatives):

- Easiest yet the least desirable, I would try to force an user logon (even though there is no actual user). This should load the *GUI subsystem* and display the main window. I'd log off again after grabbing the text of the main window title.
- At some point, the application will invoke some Windows API asking for a window to be drawn (which will not be drawn because of the previously mentioned lacking *GUI subsystem*). Maybe I could somehow capture this request and maybe within this request, I could find the main window title? Or a pointer to point in memory? Something?
- This seems the less doable but maybe I could establish a RDP to the machine itself. My thinking is that when you RDP into a headless server for example, the server is producing the visual elements that it's sending back to the client. Therefore, when an RDP connection is made, the *GUI subsystem* should be active to draw the elements that need to be sent back. In my case, the elements aren't sent anywhere but I'm hoping they will still be created so I can grab the window text.

Last, I want to specify I already tried parsing the binary for strings, in the hope of finding the information from the main window title stored in the binary when compiled. However, it's not reliable enough to be used consistently.

Awesome if anyone actually reached the end of this wall-o'-text and thanks if you did. I'll take solutions in any languages but I'm best at C++ and C#.

Comment: If no user is logged on, no GUI process is running. So there's nothing to retrieve.

Comment: It was my understanding that a GUI application will still have its process run but any API calls to create GUI elements will fail.

In fact, I just tried it now: a C# windows forms project. There is a form with a button, nothing more. I write to file before the function that draws the main form and then I write to file again after the main form is drawn.

Result: the file write before the main form succeeds while the file write after fails.

Comment: No user programs run when there is no user. When you log off a machine, all the programs on your desktop are closed. Perhaps you don't mean "logged on".

Comment: Extra: If I run the GUI function calls (*Application.Run(new Form1())*) in a different thread, all file writes succeed, both before and after calling Form1 in a different threads. It seems that no *GUI subsystem* means that GUI-related systems calls simply block.

Comment: I have simply no idea what you are talking about. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Currently, I'm doing these tests by running a remote PowerShell session. While this technically means there *is* a user logged on, I assume similar results would be obtained if I were to schedule a task and launch the executable that way (instead of through PowerShell).

Comment: You need to be precise about the terms you use. You'll want to edit your question.

Comment: Try it.  It should just work.  Of course your GUI application won't get *painted* but it will run and create windows and so on, and you can enumerate those windows and get their titles.

Comment: And yet, I don't think it does. For instance: I started notepad.exe twice: once from a PowerShell remote session and once from a normal user session (logged into an account). The notepad started from the normal user session returns "Untitled - Notepad" as its main window title. The notepad instance created in the remote power shell sessions returns only "" (empty).

Comment: Are the two processes (the one you're looking at and the one doing the looking) running in the same session?

Comment: It seems both are in session 0. When I initiate the PowerShell remote session, I **query session** and get session 0. And when I **Get-Process | Format-Table ProcessName, SessionId | findstr notepad**, it's also in session 0.

Comment: @arx: although non-interactive sessions do have (hidden) desktops and most GUI functions will work as normal, there's something odd about window messaging that can interfere with some GUI operations.  For example, inserting input events won't work reliably.  This affects locked workstations as well as disconnected/non-interactive sessions.  I've never been sure exactly what goes wrong, but it looks as if the same issue may interfere with fetching window titles: I can reproduce the OPs issue with `psexec` and `tasklist`.

Comment: You might want to experiment with various different methods of capturing the title.  The one `get-process` uses doesn't work, neither does `tasklist`, but others might.  Since your code can already be in control by the time the application creates the window, perhaps a global hook could capture the WM_SETTEXT message?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, there is something odd happening.  If I run tasklist I can't see the window titles.  If I enumerate all top level windows with EnumWindows and call GetWindowText I can retrieve the window titles, including the title of the GUI process I launched.  If you do this, Windows can be connected to processes with GetWindowThreadProcessId.

Comment: I'll try different methods in this case, one might beat the weirdness, thanks.

Comment: Turns out using EnumWindows and GetWindowText works just fine. You were both right. arx and Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this so that the solution is exposed.

It turns out *System.Diagnostic.Process.MainWindowTitle* doesn't always behave as expected. In the end, all I had to do is to enumerate top windows with EnumWindows and use GetWindowText to fetch the title of the GUI application.

I wrote a console application that does exactly this and the console application is able to start the GUI application and fetch its main window title. It works through a remote PowerShell session as well as when launched through Task Scheduler.

Not certain why *System.Diagnostic.Process.MainWindowTitle* is not the same as enumerating top windows and using GetWindowText but that's for another time, I guess.

Thanks to everyone that lent a hand.